# Is it safe to delete folders/files under run/log/journal (not var/log/journal)?

Tags: logging, log-files, journal

I'm running CentOS in EC2 and I saw this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130786/can-i-remove-files-in-var-log-journal-and-var-cache-abrt-di-usr) but my path is `run/log/journal` and not `var/log/journal`. And there're two folders under `journal` - `e76430a3b6eb....d3d1dc73` and `b30d0f2110ac....3ce88f`

So, it is safe to delete the files/folders under my run/log/journal?

UPDATE: I'm running out of disk space.

Comment: What for? Deleting files in `/run` is only necessary to solve immediate problems. It's a virtual filesystem, the files are gone after the next reboot anyway.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider My server is running out of disk space.

Comment: As I said, it's a virtual filesystem. It only exists in RAM. Cleaning it will not free up disk space.